# Can't run STM32Fxx board on utasker using visual studion 2015

Tags: visual-studio, stm32

before i post my problem i want to mention that i'm new with utasker and STM.
my problem is when i try to run the application with STM3241G_EVAL (or any STM32Fxxxx) i get this error "Exception thrown at 0x0048775C in uTaskerOpenSource.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000".
the IDE open the STM32Sim.c file and point to source of the exception which is:

```
if (ucSimulatedFlash >= &ucFLASH[SIZE_OF_FLASH]) { // check flash bounds
_EXCEPTION("Attempted access outside of internal Flash bounds!!!");
}
```

ucSimulatedFlash 0xf85e8940 error reading character of string.

by the way, the build was ok. and if i test to application with the default configuration which is using "ARDUINO_BLUE_PILL". the interface pops up with no error and the blink led works fine. changing the board lead to the error above.
thank you.

Comment: visual studio and stm32 are not good friends. Install something more gcc friendly - for example atollic studio

Comment: i'm using visual studio to run (build) the utasker. i'm using it to run the stm simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer from their github support. the problem was about the internal flash start address, it was wrong.
in the application.c folder change this line:

```
#define LINEAR_DATA_1     (const unsigned char *)(256 * 1024)
```

to:

```
#define LINEAR_DATA_1     (const unsigned char *)(FLASH_START_ADDRESS + (256 * 1024))
```

the full answer is here:
https://github.com/uTasker/uTasker-Kinetis/issues/6#issuecomment-493454061

Answer (score 0):

"Access violation writing location 0x00000000" indicates to me that the flash location or the jump to main is configured incorrectly. The datasheet for the stm32f417 says that the flash region is between: `0x0800 0000` and `0x080F FFFF` or even aliased depending on BOOT pins to `0x0000 0000` and `0x000F FFFF`.

So you should look into checking the BOOT pin configuration for the correct alias.